# How to run multiple sites from one instance of Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, nuxt.js

I am using Django as the back end and Nuxt as the front end, with Postgres as the database. I would like to have different tables/databases for each domain.

The Django code and the Nuxt code will be the same for all sites.

The way the app is set up, it requires different domains to have different databases or at least different tables.

At the moment, I am thinking I need to create a separate installation of Django/Nuxt for each domain. But I am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Creating separate installations would be the most secure and robust option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up different Code bases for every domain is not a good idea at all. I had an app that was set up that way and soon we were struggling to maintain the same code and DB structure for all the different domains. After a few domains, it will become tricky.

I would suggest developing a multi-tenant SAAS based app, where you can have multiple tenants running the same Django/Nuxt code but having different schemas in the Postgres, So your database for different domains will be completely separate from each other. I would suggest using [django tenant schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) for this. Even if it takes you some time to set it up, I would suggest doing it. It will save a great deal of time for you in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I just read the readme. I have a couple questions: 1. Can you use multiple domains, like example.com and example2.com? 2. Has the performance of Postgres decreased as you increase the number of users using the same database?

Comment: I am using it for an app currently having almost 10K users. there is not much difference to Postgres performance until now. Tenant schemas work on subdomains by default but you can override the get_tenant method to work it according to your needs.

Comment: I have read a bunch more about it since your answer and I agree that this looks like the best solution.

Comment: Would you be able to help me set this up?  I will pay you for however much time it takes. I have already set up part of it, but running into a couple errors. And I would rather just get it finished up. My email is jordan@eperimarketing.com. Just send me an email if you are interested.